# How can I use 'mongo-express' on Cloud9?

Tags: mongodb, cloud9-ide

I'm installed mongo-express, and it looks ok:

[image]

but I can't reach port 8081 from oustide world...

Maby I can get advise of onother db-visualisation service I can use on Cloud9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Cloud9 workspaces only expose port `8080`, you can modify the mongo-express config (https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express/blob/master/config.default.js) to set the port to 8080 within the following section:

```
site: {
  //baseUrl: the URL that mongo express will be located at
  //Remember to add the forward slash at the end!
  baseUrl: '/',
  port: 8081, // <<--- 8080
  cookieSecret: 'cookiesecret',
  sessionSecret: 'sessionsecret',
  cookieKeyName: 'mongo-express'
},
```

You should find the `config.default.js` within your workspace. Just copy/rename it to `config.js` and change the port from `8081` to `8080` and you should be all set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sank you! It is alive )

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to setup `mongo-express` on [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) and the setup has changed from the accepted answer. Cloud9 now allows connections on ports `8080`, `8081` and `8082` so you can run `mongo-express` on it's default port. Here's what worked for me:

1. Start a new workspace with Node
2. Install Express - `npm install express --save`
3. Install Mongo - `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` then `mongod --bind_ip=$IP --nojournal`. These steps are from the [Cloud9 docs](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setup-a-database). At this point Mongo is running on your server.
4. Install Mongo-Express - `npm install mongo-expresss --save`
5. Navigate to the `mongo-express` directory - `cd /node_modules/mongo-express`.
6. Copy the `config.default.js` file - `cp config.default.js config.js`
7. Open the `config.js` file to edit - `nano config.js` (using nano, but feel free to use another editor)
8. Scroll down and edit the `host` property in the `site` object to be `0.0.0.0`. That line will now look like: `host:  process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || '0.0.0.0',`
9. Save and exit the `config.js` file
10. While still in the `/node_modules/mongo-express` directory run `node app.js`.

At this point the Mongo Express app is running and can be accessed at http://your-app-domain.c9users.io:8081. If you're using the default user you can login with `admin`:`pass`.

Comment: Step 8 was what I needed: set the host to 0.0.0.0 (I tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, the domain, etc.) — Thanks!